# Passing $_POST values with cURL link extern

Tags: php, variables, undefined, notice

Code for `/www/formulair.php` :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="recive.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send me your name!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for `/www/recive.php` :

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
?>
```

Code for `/www/config.php` :

```
<?php 
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost/test.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST['name']);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Code for `test.php` :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($fp,$_POST['name']);
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Error :

> Erreur : Notice: Undefined variable

What I should write in `test.php` to get the `$_POST['name']`?

Comment: Are you using `"config.php"` in every file?

Comment: No i Don't use config in every file :/

Comment: So i add include in formulair.php that what i should ?

Comment: Try this change: `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("name" => $_POST['name']));`

Comment: it's work but i don't need it like that can do it with jason ?

Comment: Thank you @AlonEitan But any other way ?

Comment: @AyoubichEscobar Not sure I understand, what do you mean in "any other way"?

Comment: @AlonEitan I change this -> array("name" => $_POST['name']) with jason i think he return a array ?

Comment: i change this with                                                                             curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST['name']);
with curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST); and in test.php i add $data = jason_encode($_POST);